# Matrix operation: putting the rows next to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $A$ of dimension $N\times K$, and want to find a way to convert it to a matrix $B$ of dimension $1\times NK$. For example:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\end{bmatrix}\implies B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &5 &6\end{bmatrix}.$$

Actually i want to formulate the following problem: 
$$v=f(A)$$
such that $v$ is $1\times l$ and $A$ is $n\times m$ and $f$ is a function in a way that puts some of the $A$'s columns (or rows) next each other to create $v$. You can assume l is multiple of $n$ (or $m$). 
And i prefer $f(A)$ to be a linear function so i could use optimization techniques to find its parameters.

Comment: You cannot do it with just matrix operations.

Comment: There's one too many 5s in there.

Answer (score 3):

You need an operation called vectorization (${\rm vec}\,\left[\begin{matrix}1&2\\3&4\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}1\\3\\2\\4\end{matrix}\right]$); then you can use $({\rm vec}\,A^\top)^\top$ to convert it into a row vector.

Comment: Actually i want to define an **optimization problem** in which i have to use the above matrix operation. But using **vec(A)** make the problem non-convex and hard to solve with regular methods.!

Comment: Why would using vectorization make it any less convex?

Comment: @mathreader- You are right, it has nothing to do directly with convexity of the problem. Actually i want to formulate the following problem:  $v=f(A)$ such that $v$ is $1\times l$ and $A$ is $n\times m$ and $f$ is a function in a way that puts some of the $A$'s columns (or rows) next each other to create $v$. You can assume l is multiple of $n$ (or $m$). and i prefer $f(A)$ to be a linear function so i could use optimization techniques to find its parameters.